# Error: A value of type 'RequestOptions' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

I got below error when I compiling a  flutter project downloaded from github  .

here is the code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class HeaderInterceptors extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  @override
  onRequest(RequestOptions options) {
    // 超时
    options.connectTimeout = 15000;
    return options;
  }
}
```

and here is the mistake :

```
lib/common/service/interceptors/header_interceptor.dart:8:12: Error: A value of type 'RequestOptions' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<dynamic>'.
 - 'RequestOptions' is from 'package:dio/src/options.dart' ('/D:/intellij/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/dio-3.0.10/lib/src/options.dart').
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
    return options;
           ^
```

any idea?

Comment: Convert it to onRequest(RequestOptions options) async { ... }. Since the return value is dynamic, it should be able to return RequestOptions

Answer (score 0):

[InterceptorsWrapper.onRequest()](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/InterceptorsWrapper/onRequest.html) is a void. To modify `connectionTimeout`, you can call `RequestInterceptorHandler.next(RequestOptions)` to update the config.

```dart
@override
void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
  options.connectTimeout = 15000;
  handler.next(options);
}
```